# Sometimes java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. Sometimes not

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, timeoutexception

I have this strange error with the

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

And maybe someone of you can help to fix this problem.

The facts are these, I'm working with **Eclipse**, with a **Tomcat v7**. Then I execute a function which have

```
_call.setTimeout(3500);
```

In my **Windows->Preferences->Java->Debug** I have

```
Debugger timeout(ms):3000
Launch timeout(ms):20000
```

In my **Servers->Tomcat v7.0->Timeouts** I have

```
Start(in seconds): 45
Stop(in seconds): 15
```

Now, when I run my WebService, sometimes it works perfect, sometimes I get the `RemoteException e2: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:` Read timed out

Did I set the `Timeout` correctly? 
Because I tried to change it and stills happens the same, **sometimes gets the error, sometimes not**.

Comment: I having same Issue.. Even increasing Timeout period, I still facing this Exception sometimes... Please post your solution if you achieved..

Comment: For the record this may not be relevant but is an observation of an issue I faced that produced the same error, we ran a re-indexing of our MySQL database on Tomcat that accidentally took up 300% CPU. Meaning connection to our service threw SocketTimeOutErrors...something similar may cause issues on other Tomcat servers I imagine. To fix it, we obviously just killed the process.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, sometimes the call you are making takes longer than 3.5 seconds to complete.  In that case, getting a `SocketTimeoutException` is the expected behavior.

Comment: Even increasing `_call.setTimeout(xxxx)` I still have the problem. It's supose that `_call.setTimeout(xxxx)` have to be between **Debugger timeout** and **Launch timeout**, isn't?

Comment: There are so many possibilities and it is too hard to put all the relevant details of your setup into a question here.  You need to find someone who can help you in person.

Comment: I thought that the logic was that, but I try to change ´_call.setTimeout(3000 or 6000, etc)´ and always makes the webservice, but sometimes give me this exception , sometimes not and I don't understand why, even putting the **Debugger timeout and Launch timeout** in the maximun or minimun possibles, still happen. I look the other Questions in this forum about this exception and nothing